# Is there a way to filter messages into a certain folder in Yahoo! Mail?

Tags: yahoo-mail

Is there a way to filter messages into a certain folder in Yahoo! Mail (much similar to what is available in Gmail)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the new Yahoo mail interface. It is easier to see your new options.

1. Create a Folder
2. Go to `Options > Filters > Add Filter` (then set up your filter to move to the folder)

Comment: Is this for Yahoo Mail Plus?