# How to deal with spam mails in spam folder in Yahoo Mail

Tags: spam-prevention, yahoo-mail

Lately, my spam folder has been invaded by various spam emails. I have to check the spam folder every day because there is a risk that some non-spam emails can fall into the spam folder. As the number of spam emails increases, it gets harder for me to check false positives, so there is a risk I can miss non-spam emails.

Spammers can easily manipulate *From* and *Date* values in their emails. See the *Date* column of my spam folder in the following image. It prevents me to check them correctly by date as the *date sorting* becomes incorrect.

Actually, I was expecting from Yahoo Mail to track spam trends dynamically and block their IP addresses permanently. In this way, the number of spam emails can be reduced. Maybe I'm wrong and there is a setting for this in Yahoo Mail.

What can I do to permanently block those spammers so that I can have a cleaner spam inbox?

Below is the screenshot of the latest situation of my spam inbox:

[image: spam inbox]

Answer (score 1):

What I would do, is marking things that I know they're spam, and creating a filter for them to auto-delete them. It will decrease dramatically the number of emails even get to your spam folder.

- You can follow the same steps as [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/15323/177684) but select the trash instead of creating another folder.