# How to search and sort emails in the spam folder of Yahoo Mail

Tags: spam-prevention, yahoo-mail

In Yahoo Mail, I am checking the emails in my spam folder, just in case that some emails have been mistaken as spam.

1. But in the spam folder, the emails are sorted by their "nominal"
   receiving times, instead of the actual receiving times. By "nominal"
   receiving time, I mean some spam emails fake their receiving time to
   be a future time in order to stay at the top of other emails, which
   makes sorting emails in the time order difficult for me. So I wonder
   if it is possible to sort emails by their actual receiving time?
2. A side question: Is it possible to search some keywords in the
   emails in the spam folder? It seems not possible by using the top
   right search box.

Comment: Closely related: [How to deal with spam mails in spam folder in Yahoo Mail](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/21590/how-to-deal-with-spam-mails-in-spam-folder-in-yahoo-mail)

Comment: The field I find most useful to sort by is the sender. Then when I scroll through the spam, any messages that are being misclassified repeatedly from the same sender will stand out in a familiar group, which I can select quickly and restore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to check your spam messages one by one in Yahoo Mail if you want to make 100% sure you don't miss any real messages. So,

1. There is no way to sort emails by their actual date/time in Yahoo Mail.
2. Yahoo Mail does not let you search in Spam folder.

I am a long-time Yahoo Mail user and I also have these [problems](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/21590/how-to-deal-with-spam-mails-in-spam-folder-in-yahoo-mail).

Comment: Thanks! Does Gmail have the same two problems?

Comment: I don't know but I recommend you asking a new question about Gmail.

Comment: I agree with your conclusion but don't see your logic. Just because searching the spam folder would not find 100% of the legitimate messages there, it does not follow that being able to search for them would not be useful.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the alternative I used to search spamfolder.

- Created new folder > SPAMX
- Selected all mails in spam folder and moved to SPAMX folder.
- Then executed regular search > which worked

Comment: put two spaces at the end of a line to insert a new line. see this http://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#linebreaks

Comment: This works but it is clunky. First, to select all the messages requires scrolling through them 100 at a time. I tried moving only 600 of my spam from November and got an error message, though most were moved. I was able to search what I moved for specific keywords, but then I worried that all the moved messages had been reclassified as legitimate because Yahoo offered to classify them as spam. So I re-selected them (100 at a time) and classified them again as spam. But I received an error message and had to select spam again to get all the messages moved.

Answer (score 3):

Use the manipulated time fields to your advantage. Since no legitimate email would manipulate the time field just delete any email from the future.

Yes it is a manual process, but that is the way every email system I have used works.

The advanced search tool lets you pick the folders you want to search, you can select the spam folder. I have tested it and it works.

To get to the advanced search tool click on "mail search" without entering a value in the box.

Comment: Thanks! Where is the advanced search tool?

Comment: To get to the advanced search tool click on "mail search" without entering a value in the box.

Comment: Thanks! After doing what you said, I didn't get to the advanced search tool. Instead I reached a page "No messages found" where I can start a new search, allowing me to search emails with particular attachments such as photos, videos, Word docs, and more. I am using the normal Yahoo Mail, not classical one.

Comment: And as of 2019 there seems to be an advanced search tool avail by clicking the down arrow next to the search box. This lets you select a folder to search. Unfortunately, SPAM not one of the choices offered.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the folder number 1 for inbox and 6 for spam to search the result the url will be

> `https://mail.yahoo.com/d/search/keyword%3D%2520{put the search term }%26folders%3D6`

Comment: Didn't work for me

Answer (score -1):

The Mobile app allows you to search your Spam folder